# fscanf only reading only one integer but assigning to multiple variables

Tags: integer, eof, scanf

Ive been working on a project all day and I have come to a hault because fscanf isn't working the way I thought it was suppose to.

I am reading a file that contains something like this:

AND 0 3 2

Here is a peice of my code that is giving me problems:

```
while(fscanf(circuit, "s",cur_gate)!=EOF){
    if(cur_gate[0]=='A'){
            fscanf(circuit,"%d %d %d",&cur_output,&cur_input1,&cur_input2);
            printf("current output: %d\n",cur_output);
            printf("current input: %d current input2: %d\n",cur_input1,cur_input2);
```

So what I am doing is reading the file and checking if the string = AND (cur_gate). Then if it = 'A', i am reading 3 integers. I want to assign the first integer to cur_output and the second and third to cur_input1 and cur_input2, respectively.

The problem is that its output is:

current output: 0

current input: 0 current input2: 0

While the output should actually be:

current output: 0

current input: 3 current input2: 2

I honestly don't know what's wrong because I did almost the same thing earlier and it worked. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fscanf(circuit, "s",cur_gate)` will try to scan a *literal* `s` character. If you want to scan a string, you'll need something like `%s`.

This would have been more obvious if you had followed the "check for what you *want* rather than don't want" rule of `scanf`:

```
while (fscanf (circuit, "s",cur_gate) == 1) {
```

What's happening in your case is that the scan for the literal `s` is failing but not in such a way that it returns `EOF`. So, when you come to scanning in the integers (the buffer must have an `A` as the first character to get inside the `if` loop), they fail as well because the input stream pointer is still on the `A` at the start of `AND`.

> As an aside, unless you control the input, using `fscanf` here can lead to buffer overflow problems. There are probably [better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921) to do it.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't catch that. I was so focused on the inside of the while loop that I overlooked that. If you can't tell I am very much a rookie. Thanks

Comment: @Ryan, we *all* were once though, for us old farts, it's sometimes hard to recall :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
while(fscanf(circuit, "%s",cur_gate)!=EOF){
    if(cur_gate[0]=='A'){
            fscanf(circuit,"%d %d %d",&cur_output,&cur_input1,&cur_input2);
            printf("current output: %d\n",cur_output);
            printf("current input: %d current input2: %d\n",cur_input1,cur_input2);
```

Changes :

```
"s" -> "%s"
```